# scheduler in DBeaver does not shown

Tags: task, scheduler, dbeaver

I try to use "schedule task" on eaver. So, I make my "database task". When I  right click on a task to set the schedule, there is no "scheduler" button. The options to click on are:

"Run task, Edit task, Create new task, Copy task, Delete, Create new task folder, rename folder, group task by category, group task by type, copy, configure column, auto-size column"

The version is 22.3.1.

Is there anything that I have to download or set before these steps? what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After facing the same problem, I found the reason. The **scheduler** feature is only available on the enterprise and ultimate versions of DBeaver."

On the following link, scroll down and click on Administration & Security tab to check the difference between edition:
[dbeaver.com/edition](https://dbeaver.com/edition/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a Job in Community Version of Dbeaver, you have to use DDL commands. For E.g.

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
        job_name => 'JOB_NAME',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'BEGIN PROCEDURE.NAME; end;',
        start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2023-06-26 17:50:00.0 Canada/Eastern', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff tzr'),
        repeat_interval => 'Freq=Daily;ByHour=22;ByMinute=30'
    );
END;
```

To enable the job, use this DDL command i.e.,

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.ENABLE('JOB_NAME');
END;
```

To test your job,

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB('JOB_NAME', True);
END;
```